# How to add a class to an image by click?

Tags: reactjs

How to add a class to an image if the flag is done: true? As I have not tried, the class is added to all images, and not to those with true...

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [avatarArr, setAvatarArr] = useState({
    avatar: [
      {
        id: 1,
        url: "https://starwars-visualguide.com/assets/img/characters/1.jpg"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        url: "https://starwars-visualguide.com/assets/img/characters/2.jpg"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        url: "https://starwars-visualguide.com/assets/img/characters/3.jpg"
      }
    ]
  });
  const [classUser, setClassUser] = useState(null);
  const [selectUser, setSelectUser] = useState(false);

  const onAddClass = id => {
    if (avatarArr.avatar.find(items => items.id === id)) {
      const index = avatarArr.avatar.findIndex(items => items.id === id);
      setAvatarArr([
        ...avatarArr.slice(0, index),
        ...avatarArr.slice(index + 1)
      ]);
    } else {
      setAvatarArr([...avatarArr, { done: true }]);
      setSelectUser(avatarArr.avatar.map(items => items.done));
      if (selectUser) {
        setClassUser("active__user");
      }
    }
  };

  const blockCreate = () => {
    return avatarArr.avatar.map(items => {
      return (
        <div key={items.id}>
          <img
            src={items.url}
            alt="avatar"
            width="150px"
            onClick={() => onAddClass(items.done, items.id)}
            className={selectUser ? classUser : null}
          />
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{blockCreate()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I'm trying to set true on click, to tell the user that the avatar that was clicked on is selected, and add some kind of styling class.

And if you click a second time, then true - becomes false, in short - the choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking like this

```
export default function App() {
const [avatarArr, setAvatarArr] = useState({
    avatar: [
      {
    id: 1,
    url: "https://starwars-visualguide.com/assets/img/characters/1.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    url: "https://starwars-visualguide.com/assets/img/characters/2.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    url: "https://starwars-visualguide.com/assets/img/characters/3.jpg"
  }
    ]
  });
  const [selectUser, setSelectUser] = useState(false);

  const onAddClass = item => {
    setSelectUser(item);
  };
  const blockCreate = () => {
    return avatarArr.avatar.map(items => {
      return (
        <div key={items.id}>
          <img
            src={items.url}
            alt="avatar"
            width="150px"
            onClick={() => onAddClass(items)}
            className={selectUser.id === items.id ? "myClass" : ""}
          />
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{blockCreate()}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Live working demo https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-almeida-169zj

Comment: Yes, this is what you need, only how to do it so that you can choose two or more? So that select is saved on the previous one?

Comment: @luckydev save your selected items(object) to a state and just match with listing conditionally.